# How to do Kotlin type inference from KClass reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin, type-inference

In the code below, I'm having trouble arranging the in/out correctly such that both from() and to() work as expected. I've tried switching in/out in both properties and function parameters, but always end up with incorrect typing errors.

```
class KStateMachine(private val states: List<StateHandler>) {

var currentState: KClass<out StateHandler>
    private set
private val handlers:HashMap<KClass<in StateHandler>, Int> = HashMap()

init {
    currentState = states[0]::class

    for (i in 0..states.size - 1) {
        handlers.put(states[i]::class, i)
    }
}

fun goto(toState: KClass<in StateHandler>) {
    var index = handlers.get(toState)
    if (index != null) {
        var oldState = currentState
        currentState = toState
        states.get(index).from(oldState)
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException("to state unknown")
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: StateHandler> goto() {
    goto(T::class)
}

abstract class StateHandler {
    abstract fun from(fromState: KClass<in StateHandler>)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't need the `in`-projections at all for the `KClass`es: your code doesn't seem to pass a `StateHandler` or something parameterized with `StateHandler` *in*to the functions of `KClass`.

If the intention of the variance is that you want all the `KClass`es to represent subtypes of `StateHandler`, then you could do with `out`-projections everywhere:

```
class KStateMachine(private val states: List<StateHandler>) {

    private var currentState: KClass<out StateHandler>
    private val handlers: HashMap<KClass<out StateHandler>, Int> = HashMap()

    init {
        currentState = states[0]::class

        for (i in 0..states.size - 1) {
            handlers.put(states[i]::class, i)
        }
    }

    fun to(toState: KClass<out StateHandler>) {
        var index = handlers.get(toState)
        if (index != null) {
            var oldState = currentState
            currentState = toState
            states.get(index).from(oldState)
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("to state unknown")
        }
    }

    abstract class StateHandler {
        abstract fun from(fromState: KClass<out StateHandler>)
    }
}
```